# Am I able to match a drop down to a json object and only pull back that name

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to ajax and I am wondering how/if you can do this, I have a json file that I am currently bring in with ajax and have it logging to the console.

I have a dropdown with a list of batchID, when  batchID is selected, I would like it to grab the strain name from the json file and automatically fill the text field. The json file has batchid and strain name.

html

```
<select name="batchid" id="batchIDSel" required>
                @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.batchIDTotal.Count; i++)
                {
                    <option value="@Model.batchIDTotal[i]">@Model.batchIDTotal[i]</option>
                }
</select>
<input type="text" id="strainName" name="name" value="" readonly/>
```

js

```
$('#batchIDSel').on("change", function () {
    returnStrain();
});


function returnStrain() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.txt",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);      
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
};
```

json

```
[
    {
     "batch_id":"BCN190429-003",
     "strain_name":"BCN Critical XXL"
    }
]
```

From the HTML you can see the dropdown and the input below it is what I would like to fill.

Comment: You need to add json data/format to the question (test.txt content), at least some minimum.

Comment: So you're making an Ajax call every time the user chose a new option in the select, eventhough every Ajax call return the same data?

Comment: Looks like you're doing `Razor` views as well?

Comment: @RawlandHustle This is a form that has a lot of info on it and wont be closed until the end of the shift. They only search this once but i need less user error on the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```js
getStrainNames();

$( "#batchIDSel" ).change(function() {
  $( "#strainName" ).val(strainNames.find(x => x.batch_id == this.value).strain_name);
});

var strainNames;

function getStrainNames() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1a5hjb",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
          strainNames = response;
          $( "#batchIDSel" ).show();
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="batchid" id="batchIDSel" required hidden>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Chose a batch id...</option>
  <option value="BCN190429-001">BCN190429-001</option>
  <option value="BCN190429-002">BCN190429-002</option>
  <option value="BCN190429-003">BCN190429-003</option>
  <option value="BCN190429-004">BCN190429-004</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="strainName" name="name" value="" readonly/>
```

Sample JSON:

```
[
  {
    "batch_id": "BCN190429-001",
    "strain_name": "BCN Critical XXL1"
  },
  {
    "batch_id": "BCN190429-002",
    "strain_name": "BCN Critical XXL2"
  },
  {
    "batch_id": "BCN190429-003",
    "strain_name": "BCN Critical XXL3"
  },
  {
    "batch_id": "BCN190429-004",
    "strain_name": "BCN Critical XXL4"
  }
]
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'strain_name' of undefined

Comment: @Mike Try running the snippet.

Comment: If the JSON file you're getting already contain both `batch_id` and `strain_name`, why don't you just populate the select with options from the JSON file?

Comment: Yes that works. If i copy your js, mine still does not. I cannot hard code all the option values and as they do change

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I had a typo after changing my code.

Comment: Try my other answer below. It populates the select with options based on the data in the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution since I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

```js
// Call function that gets the JSON with Ajax
getStrainNames();

// When select option is changed...
$( "#batchIDSel" ).change(function() {
  // ...get text from selected option and apply to text input
  $( "#strainName" ).val($(this).children("option:selected").text());
  
});

function getStrainNames() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1a5hjb",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
          // For each object in response...
          $.each(response, function() {
            // ...append an option with the object's batch_id as value and the object's strain_name as text
            $( "#batchIDSel" ).append('<option value="' + this.batch_id + '">' + this.strain_name + '</option>');
          });
          // Remove 'disabled' from select input
          $( "#batchIDSel" ).prop("disabled", false);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!–– The select input is disabled until Ajax call success function is ran ––>
<select name="batchid" id="batchIDSel" required disabled>
  // Disabled option as placeholder
  <option value="" disabled selected>Chose a batch id...</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="strainName" name="name" value="" readonly/>
```

Sample JSON:

```
[
  {
    "batch_id": "BCN190429-001",
    "strain_name": "BCN Critical XXL1"
  },
  {
    "batch_id": "BCN190429-002",
    "strain_name": "BCN Critical XXL2"
  },
  {
    "batch_id": "BCN190429-003",
    "strain_name": "BCN Critical XXL3"
  },
  {
    "batch_id": "BCN190429-004",
    "strain_name": "BCN Critical XXL4"
  }
]
```